# Wamp directories not working after enabling virtual host

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I have created a virtual host for a new application in wamp.

In my `httpd.conf`

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf  //<--- Removed #
```

In my `httpd.vhosts.conf` I added a new host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myapp"
  ServerName myapp.local
  ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myapp/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host is working fine. But the problem is my other apps that run without virtual hosts are not working.

When i open `http://localhost/fistapp/` it shows

```
Forbidden 403

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using please

Comment: wampserver 2.5 - 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a Virtual Host definition Apache basically ignores the localhost domain defined in the `httpd.conf` file, so you have to also define locahost in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file as well. So your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# made some amendments to this VH as well
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myapp"
  ServerName myapp.local
  # not sure why this is here ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
  ServerAlias www.myapp.local

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myapp">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Dont forget to amend the `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to add your new domain like this

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 myapp.local
::1 myapp.local
```